# Codeigniter : how to multiply matrices array data from db?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, matrix-multiplication

well i have a problem with logic of matrices multiplication in php; the data comes from the database in the form of an one dimension array (`Array ( [0] => 1.0000 [1] => 0.5000 [2] => 3.0000 [3] => 2.0000 [4] => 1.0000 [5] => 5.0000 [6] => 0.3333 [7] => 0.2000 [8] => 1.0000 )` ), that I need to transform into a matrice. The dimension of the original array is a square number (in this case 9), so the result matrice will have two equal dimensions, both equal to the square root (3) of the original data array. 
The result matrice has to be multiplied by itself, using the pattern in the image below:
[image]

I have made some research before, but none of them were right.

i have the following code i used in the model to create the algorithm:

```
function hitung_matriks(){ 
     $query = $this->db->query("select * from banding b 
      inner join kriteria a on a.Kd_Kriteria1 = b.Kd_Kriteria1");
     $dt_matriks = $query->result();

     $data = array();
    foreach($dt_matriks as $a){
        $data[] = $a->Nilai_Banding;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";

    $c = array();
    for($i=1;$i<=sqrt(count($data));$i++){
       $d = array();
        $isi=0;
        for($j=1;$j<=sqrt(count($data));$j++){
            $isi = $data[$i][$j] * $data[$j][$i];
            $d[] = $isi;
        }

        $c[] = $d;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($c);
    echo "</pre>";die();
}
```

and the result of each array comes 0.

I want to make this code works to be like this :

[image: img]

please help me :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer:
Way to transform **$data** array into a matrice:

```
$data = array(1.0000, 0.5000, 3.0000, 2.0000, 1.0000, 5.0000, 0.3333, 0.2000, 1.0000);
$data2 = array();
$j = 0;
$k = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
    if($j < sqrt(count($data)) ){
        $data2[$j][$k] = $data[$i];
        $j++;
    }else{$j = 0; $k++;}
}
```

About matrix multiplication, I found this interesting post: http://sickel.net/blogg/?p=907
Using the exact function found there:

```
function matrixmult($m1,$m2){
    $r=count($m1);
    $c=count($m2[0]);
    $p=count($m2);
    if(count($m1[0])!=$p){throw new Exception('Incompatible matrixes');}
    $m3=array();
    for ($i=0;$i< $r;$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<$c;$j++){
            $m3[$i][$j]=0;
            for($k=0;$k<$p;$k++){
                $m3[$i][$j]+=$m1[$i][$k]*$m2[$k][$j];
            }
        }
    }
    return($m3);
}
$c = matrixmult($data2, $data2);
foreach($c as $k => $v){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($v as $kk => $vv){
        echo $vv . ' | ';
        $i++;
        if($i == count($v))
            echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```

The result is quite close to the needed pattern:

```
2.9999 | 1.6 | 8.5 | 
5.6665 | 3 | 16 | 
1.0666 | 0.56665 | 2.9999 |
```

The slight difference comes from the rounding method. If that's an issue, see [round()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.round.php) function.

Comment: i've got Undefined offset: 9 on $c[$i][$j] = $data[$i] * $data[$j]; but the logic its fine true, but its still not right

Comment: could you print the $data array?

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => 1.0000
    [1] => 0.5000
    [2] => 3.0000
    [3] => 2.0000
    [4] => 1.0000
    [5] => 5.0000
    [6] => 0.3333
    [7] => 0.2000
    [8] => 1.0000
)`

my data array its decimal form its based on database i made

Comment: I updated the answer. $i or $j should never get to 9, I expect you used **for($i=0;$i<=count($data);$i++)**, instead of **for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)**, **<=** instead of **<**

Comment: i did use your code to mine and i did excute, the second array almost right `3 | 1.5 | 9 | 6 | 3 | 15 | 0.9999 | 0.6 | 3 | `, how do i get just the second array ?

Comment: Check the next iteration, the $j one, might have the same problem. Or just copy / paste. I'll put some comments inside the code.

Comment: i'm sorry my mistake, i mean the the third array

Comment: Oh, you want to extract the line by choice? Say the first line, or the third line etc?

Comment: no i meant to say is that the iteration matrices will build a new matrix that just one line and the line array is closest from your code were `3 | 1.5 | 9 | 6 | 3 | 15 | 0.9999 | 0.6 | 3 |` i just need that result from my original array

Comment: if yiu only need that line you can select it from the $c matrix like this: $r = $c[2], where $r is the line you want. But I cannot figure out an algorithm to get you there.

Comment: The question here is: why do you need that particular line ?

Comment: i want to make the matrices result like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/faRVx.png its for decision support system (DSS) i have a program to due my degree and its all based with php i just stuck on the matrices

Comment: oh, i see, it's a little bit different, I'll come back on this

Comment: in function matrixmult($m1,$m2) the` $m1,$m2 ` whats for ? is it okayh if changed into $data thats contains original array ?

Comment: this is a function that multiplies matrices, where $m1 and $m2 are the actual matrices (as multidimensional arrays), and $m1 may or may not be equal to $m2. So yes, you can use the function for other values.

Comment: but no, the original $data is one dimension

Answer (score 0):

[sqrt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqrt.php) function is for calculating square root. If you want to loop all elements in array then remove `sqrt()` call.

In PHP, array usually zero-based index, so you need to replace `$i=1`, `$j=1` to start from 0 in your for loop.

See [Matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)

[image: Matrix multiplication]

Comment: i think i did turn $i and $j into 1